# How to generate background images?

Tags: android, background-image

I have the layout like below -

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity$FragmentRegister" >

    ...
```

and the following image - ([download link](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BxEWAcbuDzg1dFRmYnZScWpfNU0)).

How should I generate valid backgrounds from this image? What should be their sizes? Should I generate separate images for landscape mode? Should I use [9-patches](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html) somehow there?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageView` with `ScaleType` property.

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/background"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>
```

Comment: I would prefer to have pre-generated images instead of scaling them in runtime. So, the question is about sized of pre-generated images.